# cache git push delta compression for later retry on error

Tags: git, git-push

Is there a way to locally *"cache"* the delta compression created by `git-push` so that in case of an error during the push it can be repeated without having to compress everything again?

Background: I'm trying to find a connection problem and need to try pushing the same, very large, commit multiple times.

Comment: Consider using `git bundle` to make the data to send, or using some sort of wiretap to capture the pushed data. But there are no easy ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can crank the compression way down to make it go fast. Try

```
git -c pack.compression=2 push
```

or even use 1.

Comment: Tried both; still takes >>1 minute.